# Error:expression must have class type

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to display a `vector` contents named `l_anMarking`, but I'm getting this error message:

> error : expression must have class type  while trying to match the argument list '(std::ostream, std::vector<long,std::allocator<_Ty>>)

I don't understand why I'm having this error. This is my code:

#### Header file:

```
class SPSIM_EXPORT ParaStochSimulator : public StochasticSimulator
{
private:
protected:
    VectorLong m_anCurrentMarking;
    long m_nMinTransPos;
public:
    void first_reacsimulator();
    void ParaStochSimulator::broad_cast(long);
}
```

#### cpp:

```
void ParaStochSimulator::first_reacsimulator()
{
    if (mnprocess_id==0)
    {
        broad_cast(m_anCurrentMarking);
    }
}

void ParaStochSimulator::broad_cast(long j)
{
    std::cout << "i'm broad_casting" << std::endl;
    double val;
    //Get manipulated places
    VectorLong l_nMinplacesPos = (*m_pcTransitionsInfo)[j]->GetManipulatedPlaces();
    double* l_anMarking=new double [l_nMinplacesPos.size()];
    //l_anMarking.clear();
    //double var = l_nMinplacesPos.size();
    int i = 0;
    for (auto lnpos : l_nMinplacesPos)
    {
        val = m_anCurrentMarking[lnpos];
        l_anMarking[i++] = val;
    }
    std::vector<VectorLong>::iterator it;
    for (it = l_anMarking.begin(); it < l_anMarking.end(); it++) //here
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
    MPI_Bcast(&l_anMarking, sizeof l_nMinplacesPos, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    delete[] l_anMarking;
}

int main()
{
    ((spsim::ParaStochSimulator*)l_pcStochSolver)->first_reacsimulator();
}
```

Comment: Use proper indentation- this is very tough to read.

Comment: I downvoted this post because of that horrible absence of any effort to make the code readable. I'm glad I'm not your colleague at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `l_anMarking` variable is declared as a raw `double*` pointer, but you are trying to treat it as an STL container by calling `begin()` and `end()` on it.  Thus the compiler error.

You have two choices:

1. Change the second `for` loop to use indexes instead of iterators.

   ```
   for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k)
   {
       std::cout << l_anMarking[k] << std::endl;
   }
   ```
2. Change `l_anMarking` to be a `std::vector<double>` instead (and adjust `MPI_Bcast()`) accordingly):

   ```
   std::vector<double> l_anMarking;
   l_anMarking.reserve(l_nMinplacesPos.size());
   for (auto lnpos : l_nMinplacesPos)
   {
       val = m_anCurrentMarking[lnpos];
       l_anMarking.push_back(val);
   }
   for (auto marking : l_anMarking)
   {
       std::cout << marking << std::endl;
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

The compiler error is referring to not being able to print the VectorLong to std::cout

```
std::vector<VectorLong>::iterator it;
for (it = l_anMarking.begin(); it < l_anMarking.end(); it++) //here
{
    std::cout << *it << std::endl; // need an operator<< for your VectorLong
}
```

You should add something like this:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const VectorLong& v)
{
    os << "VectorLong: ";
    for (const auto &l : v)
        os << l << " ";
    return os;
}
```